# Error in addActionListener to JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing

> required: ActionListener
>   found: EditMenuFunctions
>   reason: actual argument EditMenuFunctions cannot be converted to
>   ActionListener by method invocation conversion
>
> .\AFrame.java:56: error: method addActionListener in class
>   AbstractButton cannot be applied to given types;
>
> refMenuBar.time_date.addActionListener(new EditMenuFunctions());

```
AMenuBar refMenuBar = new AMenuBar();
protected final JMenuItem time_date = new JMenuItem("Time / Date");
refMenuBar.time_date.addActionListener(new EditMenuFunctions());
```

`class EditMenuFunctions` is my class which contains the `actionPerformed()` method. I am adding the actionListener to the JMenuItem in `class AFrame` and I have created JMenuItem in `class AMenuBar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `EditMenuFunctions` has to implement `ActionListener`. For e.g.:

```
public class EditMenuFunctions implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { ... }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That did the job!! I sorry for such a silly question !! I am just a Java Beginner. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your class EditMenuFunctions to implment / extend ActionListener